# transparent image background change to black with Jimp

Tags: node.js, image-processing, image-resizing

I am uploading image to aws s3 and before image upload I am resizing image using node jimp,
all functionality is working but when I upload transparent image and then Jimp resize it and change background to black and want original image with resized.

here is code for jimp

```
Jimp.read(buf, (err, image) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else {
                image.resize(118, 66)
                    .quality(100)
                    .getBase64(Jimp.MIME_JPEG, (err, src) => {
                        if (err)
                            reject(err);
                        else
                            resolve(src);
                    });
            }
        });
```

I have tried by this options but still not working

```
                    .rgba(false)
                    .background(0x00ff001C)
```

does anyone have any solution for this
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are using JPEG as Mimetype for the buffer.

Simply change *Jimp.MIME_JPEG* to *Jimp.MIME_PNG* and you are sorted.

As shown below.

```
Jimp.read(buf, (err, image) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else {
                image.resize(118, 66)
                    .quality(100)
                    .getBase64(Jimp.MIME_PNG, (err, src) => {
                        if (err)
                            reject(err);
                        else
                            resolve(src);
                    });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

You should change background-color.

it affects only transparent background.

you do it this way `jimpImage = await jimpImage.background(0xFFFFFFFF)`